# Run simple PHP file or call a single PHP function(same as simple PHP file) which is better?

Tags: php

I have 2 PHP files (both's output are same)

First file code

```
<?php
function sampleCode()
{
//code here
}
//end function
sampleCode();
?>
```

Second file code

```
<?php
//code here
?>
```

Which is better and less use CPU when I don't need to recall or include?

Comment: Since both examples are devoid of code, there is no noticable difference. With actual content even less so.

Comment: Although this was not a great question I think everyone over reacted. Particulary given Rajesh is new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that really is the only difference then in theory version one should be slightly slower, since you have two additional tasks to perform: setting up the function and executing it.

But on modern systems that difference usually is that small, that it is irelevant compared to the load the *real* code typically creates. So this is more a question to be answered from an architectural point of view, not based on performance comparision.

Comment: if 2000 request/min. then?

Comment: Even then, it doesnt make much of a difference. When your code is interpreted there are so many libraries that are included by php itself to interpret the code for you, so how about removing all those too? it doesnt make a difference performance wise

Comment: As said: in theory there is a difference. In real life hundreds of aspects have a much bigger impact. So if you care about performance (which is good), first find out what the bottleneck is. Start optimizing there, not at some theoretical difference.